# condition parameter adjustment

Tags: python, algorithm, trading

I try to use 'IF' in python in order to achieve the algorithm that can automatically ajust the value of a parameter in 'IF' according to some stock trasactions.

```
if self.sellcount==0 and int(time.time())-self.programstarttime>600:
     if cur_sum/total_sum>0.15:
           Other Code
else:
      if cur_sum/total_sum>0.35:
           Other Code
```

I try to achieve that if my algorithm do not sell any stock for 10 minutes, the algorithm can automatically change the condition from 0.35 to 0.15. However, the code above will change from 0.15 to 0.35 after selling stocks for one time. I want the code to keep 0.15 after selling stocks for one time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**I'd like to start with a disclaimer to be careful, stock trading is not this easy and you can lose a lot of money with a simple algorithm (just as you can with a complex one)**

However, this is also a nice example to understand how to deal with running a program over time in Python and understanding conditional logic.

There are a few basic constructs you'll want to know for this.  The first concept is that to keep track of time constantly in your program, you likely want to put your code in an infinite loop.  That will keep your programming doing what you want until you are done.  This can be done like this:

```
while True:
```

Now that you have this setup, we just need to keep track of time.  This can be done easily by setting a variable and incrementing it by how long you wait between iterations.  However, we still need to track time.  Python has a nice sleep function implemented in the time module.  This function causes your program to pause for a number of seconds that you desire and then resume going through the rest of your code.

```
from time import sleep
last_sold_stock_time = 0
wait_time = 1

while True:

     # <Condition Code goes here>


    # This is in seconds
    sleep(wait_time)
    # Keep track of how much time has passed.
    last_sold_stock_time += wait_time
```

Now, you just need to change your condition value based on the time.  The full code will probably end up looking something like this:

```
from time import sleep

# The number of seconds since last bought a stock, assumes start is 0
last_sold_stock_time = 0

# This is in seconds
wait_time = 1

# ten minutes in seconds
ten_minutes = 600
while True:
    # Figure out these values however you do
    cur_sum = 0
    total_sum = 1

    if last_sold_stock_time <= ten_minutes:
        condition_value = 0.35
    else:
        condition_value = 0.15

    if cur_sum/total_sum > condition_value:
        # Do something
        pass

    sleep(wait_time)
    last_sold_stock_time += wait_time
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. This is part of my homework of a course in university so I won't use this algorithm to conduct real trading.